# Why telnet automatically send out commands

Tags: telnet

I built a server, with TCP socket. I have a client using telnet connected to the server. Once the connection is active, the server will send data to the client.

The problem is that the client will send some commands to the server randomly and automatically, such as:
IAC WONT 64 --- FF FC 40
IAC DONT 64 --- FF FE 40
IAC DO 00 --- FF FD 00
[Telnet Command list](http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/Internet/node141.html)

My questions:
1. Why will the telnet client send out message to server by itself?
2. What is the meaning of those commands, I cannot find the meaning of 0x40 and 0x00?

Comment: In case you're still looking, I found a more exhaustive list of telnet options [here](https://www.iana.org/assignments/telnet-options/telnet-options.xhtml).

Answer (score 1):

`00` is "binary transmission" meaning that it's an 8-bit connection.  `40` is not something that is standardized but whatever it is, the client doesn't want to do it.

Either side of a "telnet" connection can send configuration negotiation options upon establishing the connection (or, though rarely, any time during the session) though typically the client defaults to a "raw socket" until it starts receiving codes from the server so that the program can be used to connect to other, non-telnet ports as well.

You didn't specify what OS you're using but there may be options to `telnet` that prevent initial option negotiation.

Comment: Thanks for you reply, I am using windows 7. I have a server which sends data to a client for another application. I use the telnet client just for testing and the telnet client should do nothing but just print the data on the screen, so I am wondering why the telnet client will send data back to the server.